# GPS icon won't go away after starting activity using google maps api

Tags: android, gps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the google maps api and everything is working. However, after the activity which uses the MapView is finished, the GPS icon stays on in the notification bar. The only way to get rid of it is to kill my application (i.e. using task killer). Does anyone else have this problem?

The way I am using the google maps api and MapView is pretty straight forward. I am wondering if there is a step I am missing (i.e. override onDestroy and do some clean up). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should post your code. And please review previous questions and select an appropriate answers where possible by clicking the outlined checkmark next to the question. :)

Comment: i took at look at the MapDemo app (android-sdk\add-ons\addon_google_apis_google_inc_8\samples\MapsDemo). they key for me was to 1) call MyLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation() and 2) call MapView.getOverlays().remove(myLocationOverlay). on my atrix 4g + froyo, after leaving the activity, the gps icon goes away immediately. on my htc incredible + gingerbread, the gps icon stays on for a little while but goes away eventually.

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing this in the emulator, that is normal emulator behavior.

> on my atrix 4g + froyo, after leaving the activity, the gps icon goes away immediately. on my htc incredible + gingerbread, the gps icon stays on for a little while but goes away eventually.

This is probably an issue with your HTC Incredible.

> they key for me was to 1) call MyLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation() and 2) call MapView.getOverlays().remove(myLocationOverlay).

The only thing in `MapView` that uses GPS, AFAIK, is `MyLocationOverlay`. `MyLocationOverlay` does not normally cause the GPS icon to remain on, from what I've seen with my sample apps. Hence, again, this is probably an issue with your HTC Incredible.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to confirm this problem exists on devices other than HTC Incredible (I'm using a DROID 2). I was assuming the MapActivity super would take care of this in one of its overrides (onPause, onStop or onDestroy), but it doesn't seem to.

Following Jake's advice in his comment above, I now call myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation() from within the onStop() override, which kills the GPS almost immediately when I back out of the map activity.

Answer (score 0):

It may be old, but I didn't found the answer.

For me this simple manipulation removed the GPS icon:
* Turn on google maps (icons started to blink and changed to "Searching locaition"[or something like that]).
* Click on notification and turn off "Access my location".
* Turn off google maps.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can hold down, and then slid towards Google icon, from the drop down menu. And it should pop up saying End Trip with a little X. 
I have galaxy s5 and had this problem, usually gave the option to end trip but occasionally it would stay even once I closed maps, turn off gps and everything else.